# Is avoiding overt displays of masculinity part of the male hijab?

Tags: hijab, men

A Muslim woman may be instructed that her behavior is considered part of the female hijab, and she should avoid displays of femininity, such as *softening your voice* ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90268)), and instead adopt *straightforward behavior* ([Islamic Bulletin](http://www.islamicbulletin.org/newsletters/issue_11/women.aspx)).  I wonder if the same is symmetrically true for men.

**Question**: Is avoiding overt displays of masculinity part of the male hijab?

It seems the risks associated with a woman acting feminine outweigh the risks associated with a man acting masculine.  Nevertheless, I'm not aware of a reason there would be a distinction between men and women in this context.

Comment: I agree. I'd think if a women should strive to straightforward behaviour a man should do that too.  What do you mean with hijab because according to google it means a veil for covering your hair?

Answer (score -1):

I believe the logic here , is that Islam knows men are weak , so the hijab is the answer to that weakness , it not only covers the woman's beauty (physically) but also hides her femininity from any misinterpretation of flirtation by a man , whether a lustful man or a well-meaning man who is simply confused , also to protect her from showing weakness to someone with evil intentions .
Now putting this in perspective , asking about whether men should hide their masculinity in order to avoid the aforementioned seems counter intuitive , because male masculinity is quite the opposite of making someone vulnerable to another person's evil intentions .
However ,if this masculinity was part of a   *"flirty"* behavior from men to impress women ,etc...  , it seems that it would invoke a similar ruling .
Personal opinion disclaimer btw .
This doesn't seem to be a covered topic by fiqh ,and it is quite the hypothetical topic , so I thought I would give my two cents as a Muslim .